# Getting user language from phone browser

Tags: javascript

There are a lot of different ways to block a web-user user from seeing a page's contents based on location using the IP address.

For my purposes I did not want to install anything server-side and decided to stick with JavaScript.

This script does well to render the contents of the page invisible -to the casual web user - if the system language is English (on all of the browsers I tried).

**The problem is that this script, using the navigator.language and navigator.userLanguage properties, do not work with Mobile devices.
Mobile Devices (iphone safari and opera mini) that use English do not return a value for navigator.language and navigator.userLanguage.

Is there anyway to get this information from Mobile Browsers?

```
(function(){ 
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 

if(userLang === "en-US"){ 
var b00dy = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]; 
b00dy.className = "display0"; 
} 


})(); 


// adding the display0 class makes the body //invisible 
// .display0 {display: none;}
```

Comment: Does window.navigator.language make a difference?

Comment: Just tried, Didn't make a difference.